# Keep background layer when cropping (script)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, photoshop-scripting, crop

I know that if you choose "Delete Cropped Pixels" in the crop tool, that it will preserve the background layer, as a background layer.  However, I wished that I could still maintain this function when cropping without the delete cropped pixels option checked as well.  It seems like a silly thing to have to recreate that layer as a background manually every time.  Is there a script out there that can do this?

Comment: Why do you *need* a "background" layer specifically? I kind of wish no such thing existed and all *Photoshop* documents had an unlocked start layer without the need to set things to transparent to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning behind this is that the background layer is a special layer that **must** be the size of the canvas (i.e. the pixel dimensions).

Other layers can have pixel extents that are larger than the defined canvas size. I believe that Adobe calls this "big data."

Since you are opting to not delete pixels when cropping, then the background layer needs to be converted to a "normal" layer in order to preserve the pixel data.